# BlazeDS support on Z-Linux

Tags: java, linux, blazeds

I am working on a proposal where we intent to use Flash remoting in Flex and conntext it Java Web application using AMF. We are looking at using BlazeDS or LCDS. The final applicaiton is to be deployed on Z-Linux Server.

I came across a thread on Adobe Forums that says this will not work. Link to the Adobe Forum: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/467135

That thread is also active; however it would be great if you can answer this for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Blaze DS should work on Z-Linux.**

*Why?* Blaze DS is not LiveCycle.  From the link you provided:

> LiveCycle has some non-Java C++ components.  By their very nature, these have to be compiled for the mainframe CPU architecture."*

Since Blaze DS is 100% Java, it is therefore cross platform, and so will work on your Z-Linux platform if there is a Java-compliant JVM, which I assume there is.

You might need to scope your performance requirements, though.  While my own use of Blaze DS has performed just fine, Adobe's web site implies that Blaze DS has inherent scaling limitation that LiveCyle does not. YMMV.

Comment: Stu is correct.  "Officially Supported" and "It Will Work" are two different things.  As long as you can get a JVM and Tomcat (or other servlet container) working then "It Will Work" but that doesn't mean it's "Officially Supported".  :)

The main performance trade-offs with BlazeDS and LCDS are encountered when using Messaging since Remoting is the same between the two products.